# Including JS files inside one another via Grunt without Require.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js, gruntjs

I'm writing a Backbone.js project. Currently, all of my app code (a bunch of views) exists inside one giant monolithic file structured like this:

```
'use strict';
(function(window, $, Backbone){
    var app = app || {
        Views: {}
        Models: {}
        Collections: {}
    };

    app.Views.MainView = Backbone.View.extend({
       // etc etc. tons of code in here
    });

    app.views.ChildView = Backbone.View.extend({
        // etc. etc. tons of code in here too.
    });

    $(function() {
        new App.Views.MainView();
    });
}(window, jQuery, Backbone))
```

The file is getting a little unweildly, and instead I'd like to break out my views into their own files, i.e `views/Main.js`, `views/Child.js`.

My initial thought is to use Grunt to just concat all the files together, however I want all the code to be wrapped inside an IIFE as demonstrated above.

Using Grunt, what would be the cleanest/simplest way to "include" files inside of that IIFE? Something kind of like usemin, but for inside JavaScript instead of the markup.

Comment: You don't want each file to be wrapped in its own closure?

Comment: @crush no as I need them to interact with one another -- but I'm still fairly new to using IIFE's so if this isn't the case feel free to correct me :)

Comment: You can still interact between them, as long as the stuff that each needs is on your `app` object as defined above. I'd probably explicitly set `app` as part of `window`, but that global variable would be available in each separate closure. This also allows you to have closure specific variables - for example a `defaultOptions` variable. If you concat a bunch of modules together that have `defaultOptions`, and place them all in the same closure, the last `defaultOptions` variable would be the value used by all the modules, which is probably unintended.

Comment: If you plug them all into the same closure, you are kind of negating the idea behind closures, and, in my opinion, creating a hidden complexity. That hidden complexity would be knowing across files what variables had been already used in another file.

Comment: For example, [have a look at this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5jm7yrjs/). This is what I'm getting at. I used to want to combine everything under a single closure, thinking that would save my precious bytes...until I realized this could happen.

Comment: oh, interesting! Could you throw together a fiddle demonstrating communicating between modules in separate IIFE's? Also post an answer so I can + you. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience, I found that it's best to just leave your separated modules inside of their own closures (IIFE). The following code sample demonstrates a pitfall of combining all your files under a single closure, rather than wrapping each in its own closure:

```js
//Your big closure
(function () {
    
    //Included from file 1
    var defaultOptions = {
        label: 'Testing1'
    };
    
    window.MyObject1 = function (options) {
        this.options = $.extend({}, defaultOptions, options);
    }
    
    //Included from file 2
    var defaultOptions = {
        label: 'Testing2'
    };
    
    window.MyObject2 = function (options) {
        this.options = $.extend({}, defaultOptions, options);
    }
    
})();

//Later in the site, you decide to use some objects:
var obj1 = new MyObject1();
var obj2 = new MyObject2();


$('#obj1').text(obj1.options.label);
$('#obj2').text(obj2.options.label);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="obj1"></div>
<div id="obj2"></div>
```

I communicate between modules by leveraging events.

For example, consider you have a toolbar and a dialog, and you want the dialog to open when the toolbar button is pressed.

```js
(function () {

    window.MyToolbar = function () {
        this.onOpenDialogButtonClicked = function () {
            $(document).trigger(window.events.MyDialog.open); //you can also send it data as the second parameter if you need to.
        };
    };

})();

(function (events) {

    //Define your custom events for this dialog.
    $.extend(events, {
        MyDialog: {
            open: 'window.events.myDialog.open' //Need a unique string here. I go back later and CRC32 these to help with minification.
        }
    });

    window.MyDialog = function () {
        $(document).on(window.events.MyDialog.open, function () {
            //open the dialog here!
            $('#dialog').text('opened!');
        });
    };

})(window.events = window.events || {});

var toolbar = new MyToolbar();
var dialog = new MyDialog();

$(document).on('click', '#button', toolbar.onOpenDialogButtonClicked);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">Open Dialog</button>
<div id="dialog"></div>
```

The benefit here is that there is no dependency loading order required. In this example, the toolbar module requires the dialog module be loaded for `window.events.MyDialog.open` to resolve, but that will only be required when the button is actually pressed.

If that's a problem, you could move your event declarations to a single file called `events.js` or something.

Other than the name for the event, the toolbar button can be pressed, and it doesn't need a reference to the dialog in order to open it. The dialog listens for the open event. If it receives one, it would open itself. If no dialog is listening, then the button simply does nothing.

This example also demonstrates how modules can communicate by attaching items to the global space that are meant to be in global space. Personally, I create a "namespace" variable that sits in global space, and attach all of my stuff to it.

For example:

```
(function (myNamespace) {

    //This is assuming myNamespace.events exists already - make sure it does before calling this.
    $.extend(myNamespace.events, {
        MyDialog: { open: 'myNamespace.events.MyDialog.open' }
    });

})(window.myNamespace = window.myNamespace || {});
```

This just encapsulates the stuff I wrote, and keeps it from colliding with stuff other libraries may place in global space.

---

So, while you may save a few bytes in the minification process by concatenating all your files into a single closure, you may fall into some unnecessary trouble. With minification and gzip enabled, the few bytes you'd save from concatenating everything under a single closure is insignificant.

I've shown how the closures can communicate with each other, and hide items that are private to the module.

I haven't used Backbone.js, so sorry for not including any Backbone.js stuff in the examples. I'm sure the ideas translate.